# Evaluation of infinite series the converges to the catalan constant in sagemath

Tags: math, sage

My input:

```
f(x)=(-1)^x/(2*x+1)^2
sum(f(x),x,0,infinity)
```

The output:

```
-1/8*pi^2 + 1/8*psi(1, 1/4)
```

Why is the output like this if the catalan constant in sagemath is: "catalan"?

Comment: [What did you expect instead, and why did you expect that?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This sum is the definition of the catalan constant, represented by "catalan" in sagemath. I have no ideia what this output even means.

Comment: This is doing exactly what it's supposed to: that _is_ the catalan constant, just one of the many ways you can write the true formula rather than a decimal approximation. The only possibly confusing part in it is `psi(...)`, which is sagemath's notation for the digamma function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but if the catalan constant is represented by "catalan" is sagemath why does not use it? I'm doing another sum that I need to know if it converges to something related to the catalan constant, but the output is: -1/576*psi(1, 1/6) - 1/576*psi(1, 1/8) + 1/576*psi(1, 1/12) - 11/144 so I have no ideia if the catalan constant is in there. For example the desired output would be: 2*catalan+1/3*catalan-log2*catalan.

Comment: Other way around : why would it? That'd just waste time on trying to match a formula to the list of _every known constant_ every time sage runs a computation. You're getting an expression that evaluates to the value it should, which means it's solid maths and the rest of your program can do whatever it needs to do without any problems.

Comment: @Pinteco You might ask about how to approach this problem on a Sage user forum, since it looks like more of a discussion question. One possible approach, not sure how useful it is, is to take the result you got and solve for pi or pi^2 in terms of the Catalan constant, and then substitute that into whatever expression you have.